# CSS - Why are my nav div and middle div overlapping?

Tags: html, css

You may ignore the code that aren't the actual divs themselves as most of the code is just to make a dropdown nav, but my error may be in there.

I'm trying to add a responsive white background color to the nav div. Whenever the nav div is positioned as absolute, the white background height changes with the browser size, and the middle div overlaps. However, if the nav div is positioned relative, then the white background height isn't responsive, but the middle div doesn't overlap.

I'm unsure if it has something to do with the container division.

```css
div#Container
{
  position: relative;
}

.nav
{
  width: 100%;  
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;  /*Code to add a white background to list*/
  padding: 15px;  
}
          /*Code up until line 64 to make a dropdown menu */
  .nav a
  {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000000;
  }

  .nav ul
  {
    display:block;
  }

  .nav ul a
  {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }

  .nav ul a:hover
  {
    background: red;
  }

  .nav ul li
  {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    position: relative;
  }

  .nav ul li:hover > ul
  {
    display:block;
  }

  .nav ul li ul
  {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color: #000000;
    top: 45px;
  }
  
 div#middle
{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
    <div id="Container">
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Parts &amp; Tools</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Parts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="middle">
       <p>text</p>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish this:

- Change the floated list items to inline blocks.
- Change in children list items to `display: block;`
- Remove `position: absolute on` the list items

```css
body {  background: red;  }

div#Container
{
  position: relative;
}

.nav
{
  width: 100%;  
  position: absolute;
  background-color: white;  /*Code to add a white background to list*/
  padding: 15px;  
}
          /*Code up until line 64 to make a dropdown menu */
  .nav a
  {
    color: #ffffff;
    text-decoration: none;
    background-color: #000000;
  }

  .nav ul
  {
    display:block;
  }

  .nav ul a
  {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.3em;
  }

  .nav ul a:hover
  {
    background: red;
  }

  .nav ul li
  {
    /*display: block;
    float:left;
    position: relative*/
    /* Add this */
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
  
  /* Add this */
  .nav ul ul li {  display: block;  }

  .nav ul li:hover > ul
  {
    display:block;
  }

  .nav ul li ul
  {
    margin:0;
    padding: 0;
    display: none;
    /*position: absolute;*/
    background-color: #000000;
    top: 45px;
  }
  
 div#middle
{
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Parts &amp; Tools</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Parts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

    </div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I managed to get most of it working, the page is much more responsive now. The middle container was still overlapping with the div, but I was finally able to use top: 50% to move the middle div down. I also noticed in Internet Explorer, the drop down menu expands in horizontally instead of vertically (In firefox it works perfectly). Is there something in my code that causes this issue in IE?

Comment: I forgot to ask, is it necessary to have a container div? it contains the all the code inside the body.

Answer (score 0):

```
 div#middle 
  {
    position: absolute;
  }
```

Please also post where is the middle div in html code, it may help us figure out the structure of page.

Comment: Thanks for responding! I edit my code with what Chris Daniel Instructed and got most of my problems solved. I did add the position: absolute to the middle div, it still overlaps, but at least I'm able to move the division now.