# CSS Why do the divs overlap?

Tags: html, css, xhtml

I'm trying to create a responsive website using only css.
.I have a container which has all the code in it. Inside there, I have nav div and a middle div.
The container is positioned relative, while the nav and middle are positioned absolute.
Also, a bit of an odd question, but in Internet Explorer (don't judge) the dropdown menu of the nav division are opening horizontally instead vertically. I can't seem to find the reason it does that.

Here is the code (my original css codes were improved by Chris Happy from [css- why are my nav div and middle div are overlapping?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52711769/css-why-are-my-nav-div-and-middle-div-are-overlapping/52711871#52711871))

```css
div#Container
    {
      position: relative;
    }

    .nav
    {
      width: 100%;  
      position: absolute;
      background-color: white;  /*Code to add a white background to list*/
      padding: 15px;  
    }

      .nav a
          {
            color: #ffffff;
            text-decoration: none;
            background-color: #000000;
          }

          .nav ul
          {
            display:block;
          }

          .nav ul a
          {
            display: block;
            float:left;
            width: 150px;
            padding: 10px 20px;
            border: 1px solid #ffffff;
            text-align: center;
            font-size: 1.3em;
          }

          .nav ul a:hover
          {
            background: red;
          }

          .nav ul li
          {
            display: inline-block;
            vertical-align: top;
          }
          
          .nav ul ul li {  display: block;  }

          .nav ul li:hover &gt; ul
          {
            display:block;
          }

          .nav ul li ul
          {
            margin:0;
            padding: 0;
            display: none;
            background-color: #000000;
            top: 45px;
           }

div#middle
 {
   position: absolute;
 }
```

```html
<div id="Container">
      <div class="nav">
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Cars</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Parts &amp; Tools</a>
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#">Parts</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Tools</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      
      <div class="middle">
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
     
    </div>
```

Comment: So what is the actual problem here - were your overlapping issues not fixed with the answers to your previous question? Then you should make an effort to clear that with the people who responded there, rather than creating a new question about the same topic.

Comment: Also, please put HTML and CSS that belong together into one single code snippet here - running each on their own in separate snippets is rather pointless.

Comment: My website responsiveness was improved by the previous question. I did add a reply to their responses, but I haven't had a response since then.

Comment: Alright, I put everything in one snippet. I seperated everything at first to improve readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the HTML for the middle div, but position absolute means a fixed position relativ to the "frame" in your case to the div #container. So the div nav and the div middle overlap cause they ignore each other and are both positioned in relative to the div #container. you can give the divs fixed witdh and height and fixed margin so they don't collide. Example:

```css
.nav
{
position: absolute;
margin-top:  0;
margin-left: 0;
width: 300px;
}
.middle
{
position: absolute;
margin-top: 0;
margin-left: 300px;
}
```

Another example

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div style="position: relative;border: solid;margin: 40px;height: 300px;">
<div style="position: absolute; margin: 50px 100px; border: solid; width: 100px;height: 100px;">
</div>
<div style="position: absolute; margin: 40px 90px; border: solid; width: 100px;height: 100px;">
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Oh I get it now. Thanks! What if I wanted to make the middle positioned relative to the nav container, but still have the nav relative to the container? or would that just be bad web development practice?

Comment: Inside your container I would use position absolute. They are still "relative" to the container but it's like adding a picture to Word. Most of the time the rest get messed up cause two divs with position relative do position in relation to each other and get place each in a new row. And it makes a difference if div 1 is relativ or div 2. So don't mess around and give each a clear position.